# Problems seeing UDP-messages in clear text

Tags: java, android, c, udp

Have an urgent problem and can't find a solution for this. To give you an overview of my problem and my project I'm working at... it's about reading accelerometer values of my android-phone and sending those values to my ubuntu based Netbook. On linux side i receive those values and i intend to work with them for further purposes. But im not even able to access them. But first let's start with the client:

- The client-sided software written in Android as follows can't show neither the `DatagramPacket packet` nor the `byte[] g` in clear text:

  ```
          try{
          DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
          InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"); // Dell Netbook
          if(D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Connecting...");

          // Neues Byte erstellen
          byte[] g = {vts.getGxByte(),vts.getGyByte(),vts.getGzByte()};
          if(D) Log.d("byte-Länge:", " " + g.length);

          // UDP-Paket erstellen mit Daten, Zieladresse und -port
          DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(g, g.length, addr, 3333);
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending x-Value: '" + Byte.toString(vts.getGxByte()));
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending y-Value: '" + Byte.toString(vts.getGyByte()));
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending z-Value: '" + Byte.toString(vts.getGzByte()));
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending Byte-Values: '" + g);
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending String-Values: '" + new String(g));
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending Packet: '" + packet);

          socket.send(packet);
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sent.");
          if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Done.");

      }
  ```

  My logged data for debugging purposes is not what I'm expecting:

  12-02 14:46:30.115: DEBUG/Accelerometer x-Value :(21290): 1.7570249

  12-02 14:46:30.125: DEBUG/Accelerometer y-Value :(21290): -0.87170225

  12-02 14:46:30.125: DEBUG/Accelerometer z-Value :(21290): 4.4936256

  12-02 14:46:30.165: DEBUG/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(769): Enter sendQueuedMessage

  12-02 14:46:30.185: DEBUG/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(769): sendQueuedMessage, cursor not null and count: 0

  12-02 14:46:30.195: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Connecting...

  12-02 14:46:30.195: DEBUG/byte-Länge:(21290):  3

  12-02 14:46:30.195: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sending x-Value: '-1

  12-02 14:46:30.195: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sending y-Value: '0

  12-02 14:46:30.195: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sending z-Value: '-1

  12-02 14:46:30.195: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sending Byte-Values: '[B@40576b80

  12-02 14:46:30.205: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sending String-Values: '????

  12-02 14:46:30.205: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sending Packet: 'java.net.DatagramPacket@40576c08

  12-02 14:46:30.205: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Sent.

  12-02 14:46:30.205: DEBUG/UDP(21290): Client: Done

So what i want are the values in clear text not as pointers or question-marks (see lines "Sending Byte-Values/String Values/Packet")

- on server-side i receive those question marks too. I guess this is the ASCII-translation. But as mentioned i need the raw data. This is the Code in C:

  ```
  while (1)
  {

        bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0,
                      (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

        recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';

        printf("\n(%s , %d) said : ",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
                                     ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        printf("%s", recv_data);
        fflush(stdout);

      }
      return 0;
  ```

I'm thankful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in this code.  This line seems suspect:

```
byte[] g = {vts.getGxByte(),vts.getGyByte(),vts.getGzByte()};
```

How are you taking the floating point G values and pushing them into a single byte?

Second, the problem here is that you can't convert the Byte values to a string like you are trying to do.

In this code:

```
        if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending String-Values: '" + new String(g));
```

It is literally taking the bytes and interpreting them as characters.  You need to convert them back to floats then print them, but that won't really work for you because of problem number 1 above - you converted them into a single byte.

Comment: the floating values are converted to byte by:  
` // normalize deflection along x-direction  
 public byte getGxByte() {  
   return (byte)(gx*(-1));  
 }`  
I need byte values for the DatagramPacket.

Comment: ok, for some reason the line:
        "if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending Byte-Values: '" + g);" displays the Adressdestination of the stored bytes and not the raw bytes. Instead of just adding the variable g to the string above, adding the elements returns the expected content:
"if (D) Log.d("UDP", "Client: Sending Byte-Values: '" + g[0]+ ":"+g[1]+":"+g[3]);"

Comment: good so far, now i'm sure that the bytes are really sent over UDP and i can look forward to decode them on receiver-side. I'll find the solution for this too but nevertheless appreciate every help i can get.